# Vector Implementation C++

Tags: c++, vectors

I have attempted to implement a similar version of the STL Vector; several functions are missing but I'd like a few words of advice on whether I am indeed on the right track or whether I should change my approach.

My objective is to understand how the vector works from behind the scenes and not to replace or use it for my own applications. I would like to eventually continue this process for all the STL containers.

```
namespace mystl
{
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> values;
    std::size_t m_size;
    std::size_t m_capacity;
    unsigned int m_capacity_inc;

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> get_values();
public:
    /* Type definitions */
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const const_iterator;

    /* default constructor */
    explicit Vector();
    /* filling constructor*/
    explicit Vector(std::size_t num, const T& val = T());
    /* Copy constructor needs to use move since copy is a deleted function in unique_ptr*/
    explicit Vector(const Vector<T>& v);
    /* Move constructor */
    explicit Vector(Vector<T>&& v);
    /* Initializer list constructor */
    explicit Vector(std::initializer_list<T> l);

    /* iterator functions */
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

    /* capacity info functions */
    std::size_t size() const;
    std::size_t capacity() const;
    bool empty() const;

    /* modifier functions*/
    void push_back(T t);
    void pop_back();
    void clear();

    void resize(std::size_t new_size);

    /* element access*/
    T& operator[](int index)
    {
        return values[index];
    }
};

/* move constructor */
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T>&& v)
{
    m_capacity = v.capacity();
    m_size = v.size();
    m_capacity_inc = m_capacity / 2;
    values = (v.get_values());

    v.clear();
}

/* initializer list constructor */
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(std::initializer_list<T> l)
{
    m_size = 0;
    m_capacity = l.size();
    m_capacity_inc = m_size / 2;
    values = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_capacity);
    for (auto val : l)
    {
        push_back(val);
    }
}

/* check is vector is empty */
template <typename T>
bool Vector<T>::empty() const
{
    return m_size == 0;
}

/* returns pointer to first vector element */
template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin()
{
    return values.get();
}

/* returns pointer to last vector element */
template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::end()
{
    return values.get() + m_size;
}

/* size private member getter */
template <typename T>
std::size_t Vector<T>::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}

/* capacity private member getter */
template <typename T>
std::size_t Vector<T>::capacity() const
{
    return m_capacity;
}

/* pushes new value to the end of the vector*/
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(T t)
{
    if (m_size >= m_capacity)
    {
        /* size has reached capacity so we must reallocate a new, larger array */
        m_capacity = m_capacity + m_capacity_inc;
        /* double the capacity increase size */
        m_capacity_inc = m_capacity_inc << 1;
        /* allocate the new memory for the vector*/
        std::unique_ptr<T[]> new_vec = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_capacity);
        /* copy the old values to the new array */
        for (std::size_t index = 0; index < m_size; ++index)
        {
            new_vec[index] = values[index];
        }
        /* move ownership of the new array to the current vector pointer */
        values = std::move(new_vec);
    }
    /* input the new value and increase the size; */
    values[m_size++] = t;
}

/* removes the last item and deletes the memory area related to that object and decreases the size. capacity is not affected.*/
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::pop_back()
{
    (values)[m_size - 1].~T();
    --m_size;
}

/* clear function resets capacity info and deallocates memory.*/
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::clear()
{
    m_size = 0;
    m_capacity = 0;
    m_capacity_inc = 1;
    values.reset();
}


/* resizes the container to the argument size. if the new size is less than the old size, values after the new_size are set as the default value of the 
type of the template object */
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::resize(std::size_t new_size)
{
    auto new_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(new_size);
    m_capacity = new_size;
    m_capacity_inc = new_size;
    int array_end = m_size < new_size ? m_size : new_size;

    for (auto i = 0; i < array_end; i++)
    {
        new_array = values[i];
    }

    values = std::move(new_array);
    m_size = new_size;

}

/* a protected function that returns the container array. */
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T[]> Vector<T>::get_values()
{
    /* returns an l value reference */
    return std::move(values);
}


/* default vector constructor, with an empty array allocated of 0 size. */
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
    m_size = 0;
    m_capacity = 0;
    m_capacity_inc = 1;
    values = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_capacity);
}

/* constructs container with size and capacity of the argument, with all values initiated with the value argument */
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(std::size_t num, const T& val)
{
    /* allocate memory */
    m_size = m_capacity = num;
    m_capacity_inc = num / 2;
    values = std::make_unique<T[]>(num);

    /* initialize values */
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        values[i] = val;
    }
}

/* copy constructor: copies the capacity information and values from the argument vector*/
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T>& v)
{
    m_capacity = v.m_capacity;
    m_size = v.size();
    m_capacity_inc = m_capacity / 2;
    values = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_capacity);

    for (auto i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        values[i] = v.values[i];
    }
}
}
```

I have omitted several functions which I will continue to implement - such as shrink_to_fit, reverse iterators, emplacers, operator overlaods.

Allocation in my case is being performed using smart pointers - should I opt to use the same allocator functionality implemented by the native vector or would that be an exercise in futility?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! GOod job on your first quesiton.

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately, the short answer (IMO) is no, you're not headed in the right direction, at least in some respects. In particular, using `new[]` (even when/if hidden inside `make_unique`) can't work correctly. To make it work correctly, you want to allocate raw memory with `operator new`, then use placement new to create objects in that memory. As it is now, you're creating actual *objects* in the unused part of the memory, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Very good of you to state your goal in coding this.

Answer (score 6):

### Placement New

Your main problem (as described by Jerry Coffin in the comments) is that you are creating objects when you should not be.

If we look at your copy constructor:

```
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T>& v)
{
    // Here you are allocating several objects of type T
    // This actually calls the default constructor of T
    values = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_capacity);
    //     Two problems with this:
    //       1) Not all types have default constructors.
    //       2) In the loop below you are then calling the assignment operator.
    //          Which means you are doing twice the work you need to do.

    for (auto i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        values[i] = v.values[i];
    }
}
```

Next lets look at re-size

```
void Vector<T>::resize(std::size_t new_size)
{
    // The problem here.
    // If you re-size to double the number of elements (say an extra 'n')
    //    You are creating n elements that you don't need.
    //    Especially if the constructor of `T` is expensive of uses
    //    precious resources you don't want to do that. You do want to reserve
    //    the space but you don't actually want to construct the object
    //    until the size is correct
    //
    //    And then you want to construct the object in place not call the
    //    constructor then perform a copy construction on top of that.
    auto new_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(new_size);
}
```

This is where placement new comes in.

```
 // Create your buffer where the data is going to be placed.
 // But do not do any work on construction.
 char*  data = new char[sizeof(T) * countOfObjects];


 // If you want to copy data into the buffer you use placement new.
 T*  dst = reinterpret_cast<T*>(data);
 for(auto i = 0;i < src.size(); ++i) {
     new (dst + i) T(src[i]);    // Copy construct using placement new.
 }
```

### Memory Management

Normally there are two ways to do memory management. Smart pointers and containers. These are complimentary methods and you don't usually mix them together.

So I would expect a vector to do its own memory management and not delegate this work to a smart pointer (though you can).

Comment: In this context is  `char*  data = new char[sizeof(T) * countOfObjects];` equivalent to `static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * countofObjects))`? Both allocate that many Bytes without creating/placing the `T` objects there. Am I correct? Great answer.

Comment: @Nik-Lz Yes. But also note that both guarantee correct alignment for objects of type `T`

Comment: How so? They don't specify alignment. It's just `char`s/bytes. Wouldn't we have to prepend with `alignas(T)`?

Comment: @Nik-Lz: The `new-array-expression` (i.e. `new Type[size]`) is a call to `::operator new[]`. See `Section: 8.5.2.4 New Paragraph 11` to see the alignment properties of `::operator new[]` then see `Section 6.6.5 Alignment Paragraph 5` to see the guarantees that provide. See the comments at the bottom of this page: https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/27/vector/index.html

Answer (score 5):

I think it is well written for the most part. I see only a handful of things that you could change:

#### Use the standard algorithms

They make your code safer, shorter and convey intent more clearly.

> ```
> /* initialize values */
> for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
> {
>     values[i] = val;
> }
> ```

The above is [`std::fill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
std::fill(values, values + m_size, val);
```

---

> ```
> for (auto i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
> {
>     values[i] = v.values[i];
> }
> ```

That's [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::copy(values, values + m_size, v.values);
```

#### Focus on adding an iterator class

If you're going to extend this further, I'd suggest now adding real iterator types. Right now you're using plain pointers, which provide no error checking or type safety. Implementing iterators for the vector should be a good exercise. Be sure to also add global `begin/end` overloads for the `Vector` iterators so that you can use your vector type in a [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

- `std::vector`'s iterator category is the [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).
- See also [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) (which you should inherit from).

#### Other miscellaneous comments

- Some parts of your code are excessively commented. The main case being inside `push_back`. Too obvious and verbose comments that just describe what each line is doing are distracting from the actual code. Let the code speak for itself.
- Why is `get_values` `protected`? I don't suppose any other class inherits from `Vector`, so the expected access level is `private`.
- You need a `const` overload of `operator []`, otherwise is is impossible to access elements on a `const Vector<T>`. Same for `begin/end` Declare overloads that are const and return `const_iterator`. You should also provide the new [`cbegin/cend/`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) pair.
- Take a look at [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). It comes in two flavors, one taking a const reference and one taking a `&&` move-ref. This avoids unnecessary copies when you're storing large expensive to copy objects. Also consider [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).
- Your `clear()` deallocates memory, but that might be quite inefficient. In most usage scenarios, when you `clear` a vector you're just prepping to reuse the vector with a new collection, so if clear releases the memory you'd have to allocate again. Even though if the new collection is smaller, avoiding reallocations is still worth most of the time to avoid memory fragmentation overhead. Make `clear()` just destroy the objects, while `shrink_to_fit()` releases the memory.
- I think you made a good choice by using `unique_ptr` for the baking store. Of course that, as Jerry mentioned in a comment, using `make_unique` (or even `new T[]`) creates default constructed objects, and that's not the behavior of `std::vector`. When you `reserve` with the standard vector, the new memory is left uninitialized. But I don't suppose that's a major concern in your case. Using a `unique_ptr` is better than raw `new/delete`, any day of the week.
- Annotate the non-throwing methods with [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec). Optional, but recommended in modern C++.